# como poner un separador en un jtable java, o que una celda ocupe todas las columnas

Tags: java, jtable

Necesito poner subtítulos dentro de un **jtable** algo como en la imagen:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Alguien tiene idea de cómo se hace?

Comment: Como puedo hacer eso con un JTable?

Answer (score 0):

Eso es bastante complicado. Necesitas crear TableCellRender que controle el renderizado de las celdas. Aunque el componente jTable no fue creado para esto

Comment: tienes idea de como pordria ser el renderer, eh intentado hacer de todo pero nada funciona, o tienes algun otra idea de como se podria hacer esto